# Readiness probe failed: MongoDB shell version v4.0.10

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, connection, socketexception

While running monogodb in kubernetes it gives following error:-

I tried to change image of mongodb

```
Warning  Unhealthy  2m28s  kubelet, minikube  Readiness probe failed: MongoDB 
shell version v4.0.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-06-08T15:25:01.774+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
 Warning  Unhealthy  2m17s  kubelet, minikube  Readiness probe failed: MongoDB shell version v4.0.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-06-08T15:25:12.008+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 5):

I was observing the same error, once I've increased `initialDelaySeconds:` value to some higher number in [Readiness](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-readiness-probes) probe spec inside deployment, the issue has gone and `mongodb` Pod has been spawned without error. Actually, it takes some time for docker to pull up `docker.io/bitnami/mongodb` image and initialize socket `mongodb` listener, therefore Readiness probe indicates issue while container process has not ready for network connections.

```
    readinessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - mongo
        - --eval
        - db.adminCommand('ping')
      failureThreshold: 6
      initialDelaySeconds: 360
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 5
```

Meanwhile, you can check `mongodb` Pod for any inbound connection statuses or any relevant event.

`kubectl logs <mongodb-Pod-name>`

I've used [stable/mongodb](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mongodb) Helm chart to deploy MongoDB and discovered the error similar to yours:

`helm install --name mongodb stable/mongodb`

> Warning  Unhealthy               38m                kubelet,
>   gke-helm-test-default-pool-efed557c-52tf  Readiness probe failed:
>   MongoDB shell version v4.0.9 connecting to:
>   mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
>   2019-06-10T12:46:46.054+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect
>   to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException:
>   Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused
>   : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:343:13 @(connect):2:6 exception:
>   connect failed

When I made some adjustment and gain `readinessProbe.initialDelaySeconds` from 5 sec to 360 sec, `mongodb` container run up without any failures.

```
helm install --name mongodb stable/mongodb --set readinessProbe.initialDelaySeconds=360
```